# Restrict who can send messages to the Group(Hybrid Environment)

Tags: active-directory, office365

I have two domain in a Hybrid Environment (Active Directory and Office 365 ) the data sync from AD to Office 365, I want to create a group, and I want to restrict who can send messages to the Group from one domain. What should I do? 
I did not have Azure subscription to use Write Back.